# ImageMagick failing to convert to JPG

Tags: php, imagemagick

We recently installed the latest version of ImageMagick onto our Linux server. I seem to be having issues performing the most basic of tasks.

I am running this command line:

```
/usr/bin/convert /location/to/source/design.ai /location/to/save/output.jpg
```

Unfortunatly is saves design.jpg as an illustrator file (if I rename the file to output.ai it opens). Even if I do this:

```
/usr/bin/convert /location/to/source/design.ai -rotate 90 /location/to/save/design.jpg
```

It rotates the file and saves again as an illustrator document. This happens with all filetypes (e.g. png, bmp, etc...)

It appears ImageMagick cannot figure out what I want it converted to and just saves as the same file type.

Any ideas on fixing this?

Regards:

John

Comment: Should this be on serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

(Yes, McKay is properly right. This question would be better placed at serverfault.)

But I have an idea. By doing 'convert' only one gets a hint at the bottom:

```
To specify a particular image format, precede the filename
with an image format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the
image type as the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps).
```

Perhaps convert gets confused by the path given.
So you could try this:

```
convert /location/to/source/design.ai output.jpg
```

or

```
convert /location/to/source/design.ai jpg:/location/to/save/output.jpg
```

Regards
    Sigersted